# Add fallback typings only of untyped modules

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I inherited a TypeScript project which uses some JavaScript dependencies which happen to not have any `@types` package available.

I managed to write the typings for some of the modules, but right now I don't have enough time to do that for all modules.

My current `tsconfig.json` uses the strict mode, so I have a problem when importing untyped modules:

```
> Could not find a declaration file for module 'unfluff'. 
>     '[...]/node_modules/unfluff/lib/unfluff.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

After poking around for a bit, I found this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13348) on TypeScript's Github.

Then I created a file on my `src/types` directory with the following content:

```
declare module 'unfluff' {
    var _a: any;
    export = _a;
}
```

However, since I have several modules with this problem, it would be very tedious having to write a new typings file for each one of them and any other I'd happen to need in the future.

So I tried to create a *catch all* module as suggested in the same issue discussion:

```
// src/types/fallback.d.ts
declare module '*' {
    var _a: any;
    export = _a;
}
```

The problem now is that all typings declared in this `src/types` folder are ignored. For example, I've added typings for `ipfs-http-client` in that directory. **After** I created the `fallback.d.ts` file, when I do:

```
import ipfs, { IpfsClient } from 'ipfs-http-client';
```

Then I get the following error:

```
> 2305[QF available]: Module '"*"' has no exported member 'IpfsClient'.
```

If I remove the `fallback.d.ts`, the import above works again, but then I'm stuck in the original problem.

Is there a way of having a true *fallback* typing only for untyped modules?

One caveat is that the packages are unrelated to each other, so is not something that can be solved with pattern matching:

```
declare module 'some-scope-*' {
    var _a: any;
    export = _a;
}
```

### Edit:

If it is worth something, here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": false,
    "checkJs": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es6",
    "es2015",
    "dom"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "./src/types"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I presume you are at an impasse. Having strict mode enabled and wanting to use untyped modules are contradictory. You can either generate automated typings for the modules using the suggested tools of the DefinitelyTyped repo or disable strict mode during migration. It might be possible to use dynamic imports though to prevent this error which I usually discourage if not used properly.

Comment: Well, it is not contradictory, because I want to enforce such rules regarding code me and my team write, not 3rd party libs, which are used sparingly, even though there is a handful of them. I don't know if it's possible to have a set of rules for our own code and other for 3rd party.

Comment: I mean having intercourse with someone and insisting on protection but halfway through considering to drop protection just a little bit is kinda odd, right? Back to topic: have you tried `// @ts-ignore` right before the respective import? I am not sure whether this will actually work. Alternatively I'd disable strict mode while in the process of migrating and possibly use eslint and enfore rules using it.

Comment: It's very unpractical to expect that every module on NPM will have typings some day. While we could help writing some of our own, it's a long process (it took me almost 2 weeks to properly type `ipfs-http-client`). Disabling strict mode now means the best practices won't be enforced during "migration process", which could potentially never end.

Comment: The team can control the way our code interact with 3rd party modules very easily. So it wouldn't be much of a problem to have TypeScript disabled for those, since all there is an adapter layer on top of every one of them.

I just need a way to be able to import such modules without having the compiler screaming at us.